# Hibernate UPDATE Query setting other values to NULL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest

I am having following table for storing my blog posts in MySQL:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| PostID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PostTitle | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PostDate  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| OwnerID   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PostVote  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to use hibernate UPDATE query to update only `PostVote`.

Here is my JAVA method for same:

```
@PUT
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public void updateVotes (Posts p) {
Session ses = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try{
    tx =ses.beginTransaction();
    ses.createQuery("UPDATE Posts SET PostVote="+p.getPostVote() +" WHERE PostID="+p.getPostID()+" AND OwnerID="+p.getOwnerID());
    ses.update(p);
    tx.commit();    
}catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
 }finally {
     HibernateUtil.closeSession(); 
 }
}
```

I am calling this method with only 3 parameters in Posts P `(Post ID,PostVote,OwnerID)`, as those are the only ones I need for my query. 
However once the query is executed, all other values are set to NULL except those 3 values. 
Here is the hibernate query output:

```
Hibernate: update posts set PostTitle=?, PostDate=?, OwnerID=?, PostVote=? where PostID=?
```

Which obviously doesn't appear fine as it seems to update unwanted elements. Any advise what could be wrong in my actual query?

Comment: Have you check what is coming in 'Posts p' ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am passing only 3 values `(Post ID,PostVote,OwnerID)` in Posts P and hence remaining ones are NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by modifying my code as below:

```
try{
    tx =ses.beginTransaction();
    Posts p2 = new Posts();
    **p2 = (Posts)ses.get(Posts.class, p.getPostID());**
    p2.setPostID(p.getPostID());
    p2.setPostVote(p.getPostVote());
    p2.setOwnerID(p.getOwnerID());
//  ses.createQuery("UPDATE Posts SET PostVote="+p.getPostVote() +" WHERE PostID="+p.getPostID()+" AND OwnerID="+p.getOwnerID());
    ses.update(p2);
    tx.commit();    
}
```

The important change in above code is following:

```
p2 = (Posts)ses.get(Posts.class, p.getPostID());
```

Hibernate query remains same in this case also, i.e.:

```
Hibernate: update posts set PostTitle=?, PostDate=?, OwnerID=?, PostVote=? where PostID=?
```

however since I have fetched the  post based on PostID, all the elements of Post P will now have valid values. I can now modify the required ones and update whole Post in database.

I have also tried by adding `dynamic-update="true"` in my XML mapping file. But please note, even it will work `only` if we first fetch the posts using the `session.get(Classname.class, id)`. It just made the following difference to the hibernate query:

```
Hibernate: update posts set PostVote=? where PostID=?
```

Conclusion:

1. It is necessary to first fetch the data using primary key, in case you want to do selective update, without affecting other elements in the same row.
2. End result will be same, with or without `dynamic-update="true"`. However there will be a difference in query that Hibernate makes to database.

Answer (score 0):

use `dynamic-update=true`

Check this link it may be helpful for you

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Comment: I have modified my XML file as follows, but it still does not work:
`<class name="com.cmad.database.Posts" table="posts" dynamic-update="true">
  <id name="PostID" type="int">`